# Recursively edit a file of a certain name

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, edit

I need a script that will do the following, but have no idea how to approach the idea.

1. Recursively scan a directory /home/root/multicraft/servers finding all files named "server.properties"
2. Edit the file replacing "view-distance=(a number here)" with "view-distance=4"

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` to recursively go through directories. It can execute a command via `-exec`. To edit the file, you can use `sed`:

```
find /home/root/multicraft/servers \
    -name server.properties \
    -exec sed -i~ 's/view-distance=[0-9]\+/view-distance=4/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
find  /home/root/multicraft/servers -name "server.properties"|xargs sed -ri 's/(view-distance)=[0-9]+/\1=4/'
```

making backup before trying it.